# How to Truncate a string in PHP to the word closest to a certain number of characters?

Tags: php, string, function

I have a code snippet written in PHP that pulls a block of text from a database and sends it out to a widget on a webpage.  The original block of text can be a lengthy article or a short sentence or two; but for this widget I can't display more than, say, 200 characters.  I could use substr() to chop off the text at 200 chars, but the result would be cutting off in the middle of words-- what I really want is to chop the text at the end of the last *word* before 200 chars.

Comment: The question intends to say that the truncated text will fit in some fixed number of pixels on a web page. In this case, depending on chosen font, the space required per char is not constant. And hence we cannot assume that 200 chars will fit best in available pixels. So far (till 02-Mar-2011), all below answers are missing this point and hence none of them provide a reliable solution. -:(

Comment: Nope, not really. You can set font in a reliable ways, and then measure worst case scenario aka how many of widest characters would fit in. And if you need to be 100% sure how browser rendered it, it's not a PHP problem any more anyway.

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->truncateSafely(200)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L246) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Comment: Worth considering (exact same topic -- probably should merge pages if there wasn't already so much page bloat): [Truncate a multibyte String to n chars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58354552/2943403) and [How to add an ellipsis hyperlink after the first space beyond 170 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49422362/2943403) and [Making sure PHP substr finishes on a word not a character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1233290/2943403)

Answer (score 245, accepted):

By using the [wordwrap](http://www.php.net/wordwrap) function. It splits the texts in multiple lines such that the maximum width is the one you specified, breaking at word boundaries. After splitting, you simply take the first line:

```
substr($string, 0, strpos(wordwrap($string, $your_desired_width), "\n"));
```

One thing this one-liner doesn't handle is the case when the text itself is shorter than the desired width. To handle this edge-case, one should do something like:

```
if (strlen($string) > $your_desired_width) 
{
    $string = wordwrap($string, $your_desired_width);
    $string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "\n"));
}
```

---

The above solution has the problem of prematurely cutting the text if it contains a newline before the actual cutpoint. Here's a version which solves this problem:

```
function tokenTruncate($string, $your_desired_width) {
  $parts = preg_split('/([\s\n\r]+)/', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
  $parts_count = count($parts);

  $length = 0;
  $last_part = 0;
  for (; $last_part < $parts_count; ++$last_part) {
    $length += strlen($parts[$last_part]);
    if ($length > $your_desired_width) { break; }
  }

  return implode(array_slice($parts, 0, $last_part));
}
```

Also, here is the PHPUnit test class used to test the implementation:

```
class TokenTruncateTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  public function testBasic() {
    $this->assertEquals("1 3 5 7 9 ",
      tokenTruncate("1 3 5 7 9 11 14", 10));
  }

  public function testEmptyString() {
    $this->assertEquals("",
      tokenTruncate("", 10));
  }

  public function testShortString() {
    $this->assertEquals("1 3",
      tokenTruncate("1 3", 10));
  }

  public function testStringTooLong() {
    $this->assertEquals("",
      tokenTruncate("toooooooooooolooooong", 10));
  }

  public function testContainingNewline() {
    $this->assertEquals("1 3\n5 7 9 ",
      tokenTruncate("1 3\n5 7 9 11 14", 10));
  }
}
```

Special UTF8 characters like 'à' are not handled. Add 'u' at the end of the regex to handle it:

`$parts = preg_split('/([\s\n\r]+)/u', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);`

Comment: This seems like it would prematurely cut the text if there is a `\n` before the desired width.

Comment: @KendallHopkins: true, there is indeed an issue. I updated the answer with an alternative implementation which solves the given issue.

Comment: Would this example work for a string that contains html tags like a paragraph tags?

Comment: its really helpful to me, my headache was long `Arabic` letters and its reduced to correct words now with help of `tokenTruncate` function.. tnx a million :)

Comment: Why not adding: if(strlen($string) <= $your_desired_width) return $string; as first statement?

Comment: For a one liner `tokenTruncate()`, use the ascii character `unit seperator` which is what it's intended for: `substr($content, 0, strpos(wordwrap($content, 350, chr(31)), chr(31)))`

Comment: Code is actually wrong, and will return higher than desired length.

Comment: Love it!   I added a trim() around the final returned value.  Otherwise, you end up with a trailing space.

Comment: Be careful to use `mb_substr` instead of `substr` when using UTF-8

Answer (score 146):

This will return the first 200 characters of words:

```
preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr($string, 0, 201));
```

Comment: Almost. It seems like it removes the last word of the sentence for me no matter what.

Comment: Just wrap it in a check to make sure the string is longer than what you are testing for (same as the accepted answer) `if (strlen($string) > $your_desired_width) { preg_replace(...); }`

Comment: Tiny improvement to the regex: the parentheses make the final \S+ optional to the match, but they also capture those characters. Since we don't need to capture those characters, make the parentheses non-capturing like so: `/\s+?(?:\S+)?$/`

Answer (score 49):

```
$WidgetText = substr($string, 0, strrpos(substr($string, 0, 200), ' '));
```

And there you have it — a reliable method of truncating any string to the nearest whole word, while staying under the maximum string length.

I've tried the other examples above and they did not produce the desired results.

Comment: If the given string's length is less than the maximum length, this would cut off everything until the last space. To avoid this, wrap this inside an `if` statement: `if (strlen($str) > 200) { ... }`

Comment: One issue with this is it returns an empty string if the string doesn't contain a space.

Comment: Can be simplified to: `$WidgetText = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ' ', 200));`

Answer (score 42):

The following solution was born when I've noticed a $break parameter of [wordwrap](http://php.net/wordwrap) function:

> string wordwrap ( string $str [, int $width = 75 [, string $break =
>   "\n" [, bool $cut = false ]]] )

Here is **the solution**:

```
/**
 * Truncates the given string at the specified length.
 *
 * @param string $str The input string.
 * @param int $width The number of chars at which the string will be truncated.
 * @return string
 */
function truncate($str, $width) {
    return strtok(wordwrap($str, $width, "...\n"), "\n");
}
```

**Example #1.**

```
print truncate("This is very long string with many chars.", 25);
```

The above example will output:

```
This is very long string...
```

**Example #2.**

```
print truncate("This is short string.", 25);
```

The above example will output:

```
This is short string.
```

Comment: this does not work if the string already has a new line character (e.g. if you're trying to extract a `description` of a blog post)

Comment: @supersan Can always pre-process with `preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $description)` to replace all whitespace characters with a single space ;)

Answer (score 10):

Keep in mind whenever you're splitting by "word" anywhere that some languages such as Chinese and Japanese do not use a space character to split words. Also, a malicious user could simply enter text without any spaces, or using some Unicode look-alike to the standard space character, in which case any solution you use may end up displaying the entire text anyway. A way around this may be to check the string length after splitting it on spaces as normal, then, if the string is still above an abnormal limit - maybe 225 characters in this case - going ahead and splitting it dumbly at that limit.

One more caveat with things like this when it comes to non-ASCII characters; strings containing them may be interpreted by PHP's standard strlen() as being longer than they really are, because a single character may take two or more bytes instead of just one. If you just use the strlen()/substr() functions to split strings, you may split a string in the middle of a character! When in doubt, [mb_strlen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)/[mb_substr()](http://php.net/mb_substr) are a little more foolproof.

Answer (score 8):

Use strpos and substr:

```
<?php

$longString = "I have a code snippet written in PHP that pulls a block of text.";
$truncated = substr($longString,0,strpos($longString,' ',30));

echo $truncated;
```

This will give you a string truncated at the first space after 30 characters.

Comment: Hi, if string length without space will be less then 30 then it will be return error. and Here result will be of first 31 characters not 30..

Answer (score 7):

Here you go:

```
function neat_trim($str, $n, $delim='…') {
   $len = strlen($str);
   if ($len > $n) {
       preg_match('/(.{' . $n . '}.*?)\b/', $str, $matches);
       return rtrim($matches[1]) . $delim;
   }
   else {
       return $str;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I found yours the most useful and dependable function of all these answers for my needs.  However, how can I make it support multi-byte strings?

Comment: It seems to support multibyte

Answer (score 6):

```
$shorttext = preg_replace('/^([\s\S]{1,200})[\s]+?[\s\S]+/', '$1', $fulltext);
```

Description:

- `^` - start from beginning of string
- `([\s\S]{1,200})` - get from 1 to 200 of any character
- `[\s]+?` - not include spaces at the end of short text so we can avoid `word ...` instead of `word...`
- `[\s\S]+` - match all other content

Tests:

1. [`regex101.com`](http://regex101.com/r/bV7dJ6/3) let's add to `or` few other `r`
2. [`regex101.com`](http://regex101.com/r/bV7dJ6/4) `orrrr` exactly 200 characters.
3. [`regex101.com`](http://regex101.com/r/bV7dJ6/5) after fifth `r` `orrrrr` excluded.

Enjoy.

Comment: i don't understand the PHP documentation. i know that the `$1` is a "replacement", but  in this specific context what is it referring to?? an empty variable?

Comment: @Anthony `$1` referencing to match inside brackets `([\s\S]{1,200})`. `$2` will be referencing two second pair of brackets if there any in pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my function based on @Cd-MaN's approach.

```
function shorten($string, $width) {
  if(strlen($string) > $width) {
    $string = wordwrap($string, $width);
    $string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "\n"));
  }

  return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's surprising how tricky it is to find the perfect solution to this problem.  I haven't yet found an answer on this page that doesn't fail in at least some situations (especially if the string contains newlines or tabs, or if the word break is anything other than a space, or if the string has UTF-8 multibyte characters).

Here is a simple solution that works in all cases.  There were similar answers here, but the "s" modifier is important if you want it to work with multi-line input, and the "u" modifier makes it correctly evaluate UTF-8 multibyte characters.

```
function wholeWordTruncate($s, $characterCount) 
{
    if (preg_match("/^.{1,$characterCount}\b/su", $s, $match)) return $match[0];
    return $s;
}
```

One possible edge case with this... if the string doesn't have any whitespace at all in the first $characterCount characters, it will return the entire string.  If you prefer it forces a break at $characterCount even if it isn't a word boundary, you can use this:

```
function wholeWordTruncate($s, $characterCount) 
{
    if (preg_match("/^.{1,$characterCount}\b/su", $s, $match)) return $match[0];
    return mb_substr($return, 0, $characterCount);
}
```

One last option, if you want to have it add ellipsis if it truncates the string...

```
function wholeWordTruncate($s, $characterCount, $addEllipsis = ' …') 
{
    $return = $s;
    if (preg_match("/^.{1,$characterCount}\b/su", $s, $match)) 
        $return = $match[0];
    else
        $return = mb_substr($return, 0, $characterCount);
    if (strlen($s) > strlen($return)) $return .= $addEllipsis;
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: I've pushed an example based on your answer here: https://github.com/thlib/php-truncate-words
It became a one liner, would you be able to have a quick look for mistakes?

Answer (score 3):

This is a small fix for mattmac's answer:

```
preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', substr($string . ' ', 0, 201));
```

The only difference is to add a space at the end of $string. This ensures the last word isn't cut off as per ReX357's comment.

I don't have enough rep points to add this as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the preg_match function to do this, as what you want is a pretty simple expression.

```
$matches = array();
$result = preg_match("/^(.{1,199})[\s]/i", $text, $matches);
```

The expression means "match any substring starting from the beginning of length 1-200 that ends with a space." The result is in $result, and the match is in $matches. That takes care of your original question, which is specifically ending on any space. If you want to make it end on newlines, change the regular expression to:

```
$result = preg_match("/^(.{1,199})[\n]/i", $text, $matches);
```

Comment: There is no need to write `\s` or `\n` in character classes by themselves.  There is no need for the case-insensitive pattern modifier because there are no letters represented in your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I got another version of this based on the above answers but taking more things in account(utf-8, \n and &nbsp ; ), also a line stripping the wordpress shortcodes commented if used with wp.

```
function neatest_trim($content, $chars) 
  if (strlen($content) > $chars) 
  {
    $content = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $content);
    $content = str_replace("\n", '', $content);
    // use with wordpress    
    //$content = strip_tags(strip_shortcodes(trim($content)));
    $content = strip_tags(trim($content));
    $content = preg_replace('/\s+?(\S+)?$/', '', mb_substr($content, 0, $chars));

    $content = trim($content) . '...';
    return $content;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
Cut the string without breaking any words, UTF-8 aware 
* param string $str The text string to split
* param integer $start The start position, defaults to 0
* param integer $words The number of words to extract, defaults to 15
*/
function wordCutString($str, $start = 0, $words = 15 ) {
    $arr = preg_split("/[\s]+/",  $str, $words+1);
    $arr = array_slice($arr, $start, $words);
    return join(' ', $arr);
}
```

Usage:

```
$input = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna liqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.';
echo wordCutString($input, 0, 10);
```

This will output first 10 words.

The `preg_split` function is used to split a string into substrings. The boundaries along which the string is to be split, are specified using a regular expressions pattern.

`preg_split` function takes 4 parameters, but only the first 3 are relevant to us right now.

First Parameter – Pattern
The first parameter is the regular expressions pattern along which the string is to be split. In our case, we want to split the string across word boundaries. Therefore we use a predefined character class `\s` which matches white space characters such as space, tab, carriage return and line feed.

Second Parameter – Input String
The second parameter is the long text string which we want to split.

Third Parameter – Limit
The third parameter specifies the number of substrings which should be returned. If you set the limit to `n`, preg_split will return an array of n elements. The first `n-1` elements will contain the substrings. The last `(n th)` element will contain the rest of the string.

Comment: There is no benefit in writing `\s` inside of a character class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
function word_shortener($text, $words=10, $sp='...'){

  $all = explode(' ', $text);
  $str = '';
  $count = 1;

  foreach($all as $key){
    $str .= $key . ($count >= $words ? '' : ' ');
    $count++;
    if($count > $words){
      break;
    }
  }

  return $str . (count($all) <= $words ? '' : $sp);

}
```

Examples:

```
word_shortener("Hello world, this is a text", 3); // Hello world, this...
word_shortener("Hello world, this is a text", 3, ''); // Hello world, this
word_shortener("Hello world, this is a text", 3, '[read more]'); // Hello world, this[read more]
```

---

How it works:

**1. Explode space from input text:**

```
$all = explode(' ', $text);
```

for example, if `$text` will be "Hello world" then `$all` is an array with exploded values:

`["Hello", "world"]`

**2. For each word:**

Select each element in exploded text:

```
foreach($all as $key){...
```

Append current word(`$key`) to `$str` and space if it's the last word:

```
$str .= $key . ($count >= $words ? '' : ' ');
```

Then add 1 to `$count` and check if it's greater than max limit(`$words`) break the loop:

```
if($count > $words){
   break;
}
```

Then return `$str` and separator(`$sp`) only if the final text is less than input text:

```
return $str . (count($all) <= $words ? '' : $sp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Justin Poliey's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-chara/80030#80030):

```
// Trim very long text to 120 characters. Add an ellipsis if the text is trimmed.
if(strlen($very_long_text) > 120) {
  $matches = array();
  preg_match("/^(.{1,120})[\s]/i", $very_long_text, $matches);
  $trimmed_text = $matches[0]. '...';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a function that does almost what you want, if you'll do a few edits, it will fit exactly:

```
<?php
function stripByWords($string,$length,$delimiter = '<br>') {
    $words_array = explode(" ",$string);
    $strlen = 0;
    $return = '';
    foreach($words_array as $word) {
        $strlen += mb_strlen($word,'utf8');
        $return .= $word." ";
        if($strlen >= $length) {
            $strlen = 0;
            $return .= $delimiter;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how i did it:

```
$string = "I appreciate your service & idea to provide the branded toys at a fair rent price. This is really a wonderful to watch the kid not just playing with variety of toys but learning faster compare to the other kids who are not using the BooksandBeyond service. We wish you all the best";

print_r(substr($string, 0, strpos(wordwrap($string, 250), "\n")));
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is a rather old question, I figured I would provide an alternative, as it was not mentioned and valid for PHP 4.3+.

You can use the [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) family of functions to truncate text, by using the  `%.ℕs` precision modifier.

> A period `.` followed by an integer who's meaning depends on the
>   specifier:
>
> - For e, E, f and F specifiers: this is the number of digits to be    printed after the decimal point (by default, this is 6).
> - For g and G    specifiers: this is the maximum number of significant digits to be    printed.
> - **For s specifier: it acts as a cutoff point, setting a maximum character limit to the string**

### Simple Truncation https://3v4l.org/QJDJU

```php
$string = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var_dump(sprintf('%.10s', $string));
```

**Result**

```
string(10) "0123456789"
```

---

### Expanded Truncation https://3v4l.org/FCD21

Since `sprintf` functions similarly to `substr` and will partially cut off words. The below approach will ensure words are not cutoff by using `strpos(wordwrap(..., '[break]'), '[break]')` with a special delimiter. This allows us to retrieve the position and ensure we do not match on standard sentence structures.

Returning a string without partially cutting off words and that does not exceed the specified width, while preserving line-breaks if desired.

```php
function truncate($string, $width, $on = '[break]') {
    if (strlen($string) > $width && false !== ($p = strpos(wordwrap($string, $width, $on), $on))) {
        $string = sprintf('%.'. $p . 's', $string);
    }
    return $string;
}
var_dump(truncate('0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 20));

var_dump(truncate("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.", 20));

var_dump(truncate("Lorem Ipsum\nis simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.", 20));
```

**Result**

```
/* 
string(36) "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"  
string(14) "Lorem Ipsum is" 
string(14) "Lorem Ipsum
is" 
*/
```

Results using `wordwrap($string, $width)` or `strtok(wordwrap($string, $width), "\n")`

```
/*
string(14) "Lorem Ipsum is"
string(11) "Lorem Ipsum"
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Multiple Use-Case Function

- Allow break-word as an option
- Allow character count as an option
- Allow ellipsis character to be specified and added, or not

I wrote this for my project based on my original **quest for truncating by characters without breaking words** and thought it might be of use to someone, should they need to truncate in different ways throughout their project as well.

You could make your own adjustments where needed, adding in more options, validations, etc.

```php
/**
 * Truncate text by characters
 *
 * @param $text String - text to truncate
 * @param $chars Integer - number of characters to truncate to - default 40
 * @param $breakWord Boolean - if true, will break on word boundaries - when false, could lead to strings longer than $chars
 * @param $ellipsis String - if set, will append to truncated text, '…' character by default
 */
public static function truncateTextByChars(
    $text,
    $chars = 40,
    $breakWord = false,
    $ellipsis = '…')
{
    if (empty($text)) {
        return null;
    }

    if ($breakWord) {
        $truncate = substr($text, 0, $chars);
        return $ellipsis && strlen($truncate) < strlen($text)
            ? $truncate . $ellipsis
            : $truncate;
    }

    // This will allow strings longer than $chars
    // eg. if the LAST WORD is within the first $chars chars
    if (strlen($text) > $chars) {
        $shortened = (substr($text,0,strpos($text,' ',$chars)));
        // make sure we don't cut off mid last-word and wind up with nothing
        $final = $ellipsis && strlen($shortened) > 0
            ? $shortened . $ellipsis
            : $text;
    } else {
        $final = $text;
    }
    return $final;
}
```

#### Examples:

```php
// Defaults - chars:40; breakWord:false; ellipsis:'…',
>>> HelpersTrait::truncateTextByChars('DC Office of Cable Television, Film, Music, and Entertainment');
=> "DC Office of Cable Television, Film, Music,…"

// breakWord:true; ellipsis:false
>>> HelpersTrait::truncateTextByChars('DC Office of Cable Television, Film, Music, and Entertainment', 40, true, false);
=> "DC Office of Cable Television, Film, Mus"

// breakWord:true; ellipsis:'…'
>>> HelpersTrait::truncateTextByChars('DC Office of Cable Television, Film, Music, and Entertainment', 40, true);
=> "DC Office of Cable Television, Film, Mus…"
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a function more similar to substr, and using the idea of @Dave.

```
function substr_full_word($str, $start, $end){
    $pos_ini = ($start == 0) ? $start : stripos(substr($str, $start, $end), ' ') + $start;
    if(strlen($str) > $end){ $pos_end = strrpos(substr($str, 0, ($end + 1)), ' '); } // IF STRING SIZE IS LESSER THAN END
    if(empty($pos_end)){ $pos_end = $end; } // FALLBACK
    return substr($str, $pos_ini, $pos_end);
}
```

Ps.: The full length cut may be less than substr.

Answer (score 0):

Added IF/ELSEIF statements to the code from [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4665347/2321998) and [AmalMurali](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-chara/4665347#comment36125374_4665347) for handling strings without spaces

```
if ((strpos($string, ' ') !== false) && (strlen($string) > 200)) { 
    $WidgetText = substr($string, 0, strrpos(substr($string, 0, 200), ' ')); 
} 
elseif (strlen($string) > 200) {
    $WidgetText = substr($string, 0, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this works:

```
function abbreviate_string_to_whole_word($string, $max_length, $buffer) {
    if (strlen($string) > $max_length) {
        $string_cropped = substr($string, 0, $max_length - $buffer);
        $last_space = strrpos($string_cropped, " ");
        if ($last_space > 0) {
            $string_cropped = substr($string_cropped, 0, $last_space);
        }
        $abbreviated_string = $string_cropped . "&nbsp;...";
    }
    else {
        $abbreviated_string = $string;
    }
    return $abbreviated_string;
}
```

The buffer allows you to adjust the length of the returned string.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I've seen, all the solutions here are only valid for the case when the starting point is fixed.
>
> Allowing you to turn this:
>
> ```php
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna liqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
> ```
>
> Into this:
>
> ```php
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...
> ```
>
> #### What if you want to truncate words surrounding a specific set of keywords?

## Truncate the text surrounding a specific set of keywords.

The goal is to be able to convert this:

```php
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna liqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
```

Into this:

```php
...consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor...
```

Which is a very common situation when displaying search results, excerpts, etc. To achieve this we can use these two methods combined:

```php
    /**
     * Return the index of the $haystack matching $needle,
     * or NULL if there is no match.
     *
     * This function is case-insensitive  
     * 
     * @param string $needle
     * @param array $haystack
     * @return false|int
     */
    function regexFindInArray(string $needle, array $haystack): ?int
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($haystack); $i++) {
            if (preg_match('/' . preg_quote($needle) . '/i', $haystack[$i]) === 1) {
                return $i;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * If the keyword is not present, it returns the maximum number of full 
     * words that the max number of characters provided by $maxLength allow,
     * starting from the left.
     *
     * If the keyword is present, it adds words to both sides of the keyword
     * keeping a balanace between the length of the suffix and the prefix.
     *
     * @param string $text
     * @param string $keyword
     * @param int $maxLength
     * @param string $ellipsis
     * @return string
     */
    function truncateWordSurroundingsByLength(string $text, string $keyword, 
            int $maxLength, string $ellipsis): string
    {
        if (strlen($text) < $maxLength) {
            return $text;
        }

        $pattern = '/' . '^(.*?)\s' .
                   '([^\s]*' . preg_quote($keyword) . '[^\s]*)' .
                   '\s(.*)$' . '/i';
        preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);

        // break everything into words except the matching keywords, 
        // which can contain spaces
        if (count($matches) == 4) {
            $words = preg_split("/\s+/", $matches[1], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
            $words[] = $matches[2];
            $words = array_merge($words, 
                              preg_split("/\s+/", $matches[3], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
        } else {
            $words = preg_split("/\s+/", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        }

        // find the index of the matching word
        $firstMatchingWordIndex = regexFindInArray($keyword, $words) ?? 0;

        $length = false;
        $prefixLength = $suffixLength = 0;
        $prefixIndex = $firstMatchingWordIndex - 1;
        $suffixIndex = $firstMatchingWordIndex + 1;

        // Initialize the text with the matching word
        $text = $words[$firstMatchingWordIndex];

        while (($prefixIndex >= 0 or $suffixIndex <= count($words))
                and strlen($text) < $maxLength and strlen($text) !== $length) {
            $length = strlen($text);
            if (isset($words[$prefixIndex])
                and (strlen($text) + strlen($words[$prefixIndex]) <= $maxLength)
                and ($prefixLength <= $suffixLength 
                     or strlen($text) + strlen($words[$suffixIndex]) <= $maxLength)) {
                $prefixLength += strlen($words[$prefixIndex]);
                $text = $words[$prefixIndex] . ' ' . $text;
                $prefixIndex--;
            }
            if (isset($words[$suffixIndex])
                and (strlen($text) + strlen($words[$suffixIndex]) <= $maxLength)
                and ($suffixLength <= $prefixLength 
                     or strlen($text) + strlen($words[$prefixIndex]) <= $maxLength)) {
                $suffixLength += strlen($words[$suffixIndex]);
                $text = $text . ' ' . $words[$suffixIndex];
                $suffixIndex++;
            }
        }

        if ($prefixIndex > 0) {
            $text = $ellipsis . ' ' . $text;
        }
        if ($suffixIndex < count($words)) {
            $text = $text . ' ' . $ellipsis;
        }

        return $text;
    }
```

Now you can do:

```php
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do' .
        'iusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna liqua. Ut enim' .
        'ad minim veniam.';

$text = truncateWordSurroundingsByLength($text, 'elit', 25, '...');

var_dump($text); // string(32) "... adipisicing elit, sed do ..."
```

[Run code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4f8a17dba1b7937c00a496424731b17917b9af9e).

Comment: It appears that you have stretched the scope of this question and this has resulted in an answer which is very convoluted and unlikely to help the researchers that navigated to this page.  It would probably be better if you moved your answer to a better suited page or if there isn't one, then post your own question and self-answer it.  Also, `[^\s]` is more simply expressed as `\S`.  I generally avoid `or` and `and` in php to prevent precedence issues.  `preg_quote()` doesn't have a default delimiter, so you should supply it one.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old, but...

```
function _truncate($str, $limit) {
    if(strlen($str) < $limit)
        return $str;
    $uid = uniqid();
    return array_shift(explode($uid, wordwrap($str, $limit, $uid)));
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  Why are we seeing `uniqid()` used here?

Answer (score -1):

I used this before

```
<?php
    $your_desired_width = 200;
    $string = $var->content;
    if (strlen($string) > $your_desired_width) {
        $string = wordwrap($string, $your_desired_width);
        $string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, "\n")) . " More...";
    }
    echo $string;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is the easiest way to do it:

```
$lines = explode('♦♣♠',wordwrap($string, $length, '♦♣♠'));
$newstring = $lines[0] . ' &bull; &bull; &bull;';
```

I'm using the special characters to split the text and cut it.

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

the following code will remove ','. If you have anyother character or sub-string, you may use that instead of ','

```
substr($string, 0, strrpos(substr($string, 0, $comparingLength), ','))
```

// if you have another string account for

```
substr($string, 0, strrpos(substr($string, 0, $comparingLength-strlen($currentString)), ','))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function trunc($phrase, $max_words) {
       $phrase_array = explode(' ',$phrase);
       if(count($phrase_array) > $max_words && $max_words > 0)
          $phrase = implode(' ',array_slice($phrase_array, 0, $max_words)).'...';
       return $phrase;
    }
```

Comment: Does not answer the question, counts words instead of characters.

Comment: This answer does not explain why it works, how can one learn from it?

Answer (score -2):

May be this will help someone:

```
<?php

    $string = "Your line of text";
    $spl = preg_match("/([, \.\d\-''\"\"_()]*\w+[, \.\d\-''\"\"_()]*){50}/", $string, $matches);
    if (isset($matches[0])) {
        $matches[0] .= "...";
        echo "<br />" . $matches[0];
    } else {
        echo "<br />" . $string;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score -4):

Here you can try this

```
substr( $str, 0, strpos($str, ' ', 200) );
```

Comment: That solution was already mentioned in other answers.  The problem with it is it fails if the string is less than the 200 character length, or if it doesn't contain any spaces.  It also doesn't limit the string to 200 characters, instead it breaks the string at the space *after* 200 characters, which is usually not what you want.