# Truncate String on closest word boundary

Tags: java, string

Is it possible to truncate a Java string to the closest word boundary after a number of characters. Similar to the PHP wordwrap() function, shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-charac).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a `java.text.BreakIterator`, something like this:

```
String s = ...;
int number_chars = ...;
BreakIterator bi = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();
bi.setText(s);
int first_after = bi.following(number_chars);
// to truncate:
s = s.substring(0, first_after);
```

Comment: This is great thanks, although would aa bi.truncateAt() have been too much to ask for? :)

Comment: Make sure you test that number_chars is not larger than s.length(), otherwise you get an exception.  FYI, I tried to edit the java to reflect this fact, but the edit was rejected.

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expression

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^.{0,10}\\b").matches(str);
m.find();
String first10char = m.group(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

With the first approach you will end up with a length bigger than number_chars.  If you need an exact maximum or less, like for a Twitter message, see my implementation below.

Note that the regexp approach uses a space to delimit the words, while BreakIterator breaks up words even if they have commas and other characters.  This is more desirable.

Here is my full function:

```
/**
     * Truncate text to the nearest word, up to a maximum length specified.
     * 
     * @param text
     * @param maxLength
     * @return
     */
    private String truncateText(String text, int maxLength) {
        if(text != null && text.length() > maxLength) {
            BreakIterator bi = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();
            bi.setText(text);

            if(bi.isBoundary(maxLength-1)) {
                return text.substring(0, maxLength-2);
            } else {
                int preceding = bi.preceding(maxLength-1);
                return text.substring(0, preceding-1);
            }
        } else {
            return text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `BreakIterator` is not really straightforward when breaking sentence is URL, it breaks URL not very nice way. I rather used mine solution:

```
public static String truncateText(String text, int maxLength) {
    if (text != null && text.length() < maxLength) {
        return text;
    }
    List<String> words = Splitter.on(" ").splitToList(text);
    List<String> truncated = new ArrayList<>();
    int totalCount = 0;
    for (String word : words) {
        int wordLength = word.length();
        if (totalCount + 1 + wordLength > maxLength) { // +1 because of space
            break;
        }
        totalCount += 1; // space
        totalCount += wordLength;
        truncated.add(word);
    }
    String truncResult = Joiner.on(" ").join(truncated);
    return truncResult + " ...";
}
```

Splitter/Joiner is from guava. I am also adding `...` at the end in my use cas (can be ommited).