# split string after some chars with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-replace

I found this code which will match at most 300 chars, then break at the next nearest word-break:

```
 $var = 'This is a test text 1234567890 test check12.' # 44 chars
 preg_match('/^.{0,300}(?:.*?)\b/iu', $var, $matches);
 echo $matches[0];
```

44 is lower than 300, so I expect the output to be the same like $var.

But the output is:

```
 This is a test text 1234567890 test check12   # 43 chars
```

$matches[0] is not giving me the dot at the end, however $var does. Anyone can tell me how to get the full string (with the dot)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get the expected result by:

- Removing the `\b`
- Replacing `\b` with `$`

**EDIT:**

In your pattern the dot at the end of the string is acting as a word boundary, so you are able to match everything before the dot. If you put a `.*` after the `\b` , you'll see that it will match the dot.

See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for more info on how word boundaries in regex work.

Answer (score 2):

Using preg_match to break at 300 chars seems like a bad idea.  Why don't you just use:

```
substr($var, 0, strpos($var, ' ', 300));
```

That will give you the first 300 chars broken at the next whitespace without using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
'/^.{300}(?:.*?)\b|^.*{0,300}/u'
```

I'm not sure why you want this though. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259282/how-to-shorten-a-string-without-slicing-through-a-word-while-keeping-within-a-cha/2259301#2259301) is my answer to a similar question, but cutting at the previous nearest space.

Answer (score 0):

In your

> (?:.*?)

You should get rid of the * I think. This means that it must match at least once, but up to infinite times. So you wil find that your period is in the second match.

TO be honest, I would just use the pattern

```
 preg_match('/^(.){0,300}\b/iu', $var, $matches);
```

Comment: '*' means 0 or more.  '+' means 1 or more.