# Stripping and trimming a list of keywords?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Truncate a string in PHP to the word closest to a certain number of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-chara)

I have a string of keywords like below

```
word1, word3, word3, word4, word5
```

Now say this list is 400 chars long. I only want the keywords upto the 255 character but I also want to trim the last word as it may only be half a word.

Say I trim the keyword list and end up with this

```
word1, word3, word3, wo
```

How do I make sure I trim the last word only if it's half a word

Any ideas on this? I don't know where to start

By the way I'm using PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = wordwrap($str, 28);
$str = explode("\n", $str);
$str = $str[0]
```