# Concatenation of PHP echo with div tag containing php

Tags: php, html, echo, substr

I am using Javascript to hide / show a blog-post stored in a mysql table. The script for doing this is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function unhide(divID) {
        var item = document.getElementById(divID);
        if (item) {
            item.className = (item.className == 'hidden') ? 'unhidden' : 'hidden';
        }
    }
</script>
```

This links to some css styling:

```
.hidden {
 display: none;}
.unhidden {
 display: inline;}
```

I am calling the script via a href styles as a button:

```
<a class=button href="javascript:unhide('first_post');">More</a>
```

As for the content I originally tried the following to initially show a small section of text, then the rest after the link is clicked:

```
<?php $var = mysql_result($result,0,"post_text"); ?>

<?php echo substr($var, 0, 400); ?>
<div id="first_post" class = "hidden">
  <?php echo substr($var, 400, 5000)?>
</div>
```

However where the two sets of sub-strings join there is a space. For example if the first sub-string ends in **"the tree's hav"** and the second sub-string starts **"e eyes you know"** the concatenation results in **"the trees hav e eyes you know"**

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Just a small thing: you're writing `class=button`. But should probably be `class="button"`.

Comment: @Marnix: It doesn't seem to affect it either way, not sure why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove newlines between `<?php ?>` and `<div>` tags - this should help you get rid of spaces.

```
<?php echo substr($var, 0, 400); ?><div id="first_post" class = "hidden"><?php echo substr($var, 400, 5000)?></div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, turned out to be a case of making my code easier to read actually messing up what I wanted it to to. Will take this as a life lesson haha :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is you want to truncate string from the end of the word rather than giving link somewhere in between. That's what I see as permanent solution...

When I googled up expecting that PHP would have something available out of the box found following 2 article which might help you.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/truncate-string-by-words/

[How to Truncate a string in PHP to the word closest to a certain number of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-chara)

They are not exactly what you're looking for but they can be of great help if you take inspiration from the concepts.