# how to extract a sentence or word count from a variable in php?

Tags: php

The text variable below contains 10 sentences.

```
$txt = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.';
```

If the variable contains value coming from a user who enters a bunch of texts in a textarea for example, how do I know how many paragraphs the variable contains?

also how do I extract the variable for certain number of words say up to 100 words for example but if that 100 word count does not end with a complete sentence, the script will give me the complete sentence containing that 100 words or how many words there is in a complete sentence close to a 100 words count limit that i set.

is this possible in php?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-chara

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the total length and divide it by the predefined value for the paragragh
2. Use `substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ]`

See also: [substr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
$input = $_POST['textarea'];
$output = array();
preg_match_all("/<p>(.*)<\/p>/",$input,$output);
$paragraphs = count($output);
```