# How with PHP to count words and then add "More"?

Tags: php

i have this:

```
<? if (strlen($item->introtext) > 300) { 
    echo substr($item->introtext, 0,300)." More"; 
    } else { 
    echo $item->introtext;}
?>
```

But it counts symbols, i want it to count **words**. E.g. after 10th word to add "More".

How to do this, i guess I must change "strlen" with smthing else?

Comment: Looks like you want something like this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-chara

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use function **[`str_word_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)**. Which will gave count as well as array of words as per second argument. For more info

Comment: I tried to use this function, but i cannot make it work... Can you provide/show a example

Comment: @user1978483: The manual page linked has the examples you need. Also, next time, when you ask a question, make sure to mention what you've tried in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Second argument set as 0 will give count of words. ( As manual page says :) )

Comment: Dont you think if I asked such a simple question, that means I am not a php programmer? You tell me to look at the example form your link, I realy dont get it there... But anyway its okey, let's count this question CLOSED.

Answer (score 1):

You can split by a space, and count how many words you have:

```
$words = preg_split("/\s+/", $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

#### Note:

- I use `preg_split` to overcome the consecutive spaces problem.
- `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` doesn't include empty words.

`$words` now contains an array of all words, you can [`count()`](http://php.net/count) it to know how many you have, and [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) to get a string back from it.

Answer (score 0):

You could explode the string on spaces. That should give you an array with entries for every word. A count of the array would then tell you the amount of words. There could be some false-positives with this technique since everything that is surrounded by [space] would count as a word.

Comment: You aren't taking into account what happens when multiple spaces are used consecutively.

Comment: Yes, that's why is said that this method isn't exact. Though a better answer has aleady been given. Use the build in function str_word_count