# Take Random string and make it 155 characters ending at nearest word

Tags: php, strlen

I am building a system to create dynamic descriptions for meta tags.  It takes the post on the page and feeds it into a function which stripes out everything unnecessary and then takes the strlen see that its to large and creates a list of words.  Now, I need to remove the right amount of words to bring the string down to 155 characters or 152 and I will add an ellipsis.

**Example String** (None of this is actual code its meant for sudo code)

`$string = "Hello lovely Solia Avatar Community, I have a little problem and I need your help. I used to have Paint Tool SAI but my laptop ate a lot of my files, one of them being SAI. Now I am trying to get it back but I lost the website I got it from. I keep finding a website to buy it from for about $70.";`

`echo strlen($string);` = 296

```
if(strlen($string) > 155) {
    // Get word amount
    $words = preg_split('/\s+/', ltrim($string), 155 + 1);
}
```

Now, I have the words in an array and I need to take that array and bring it down to a total strlen of 155 and stop at the nearest word and not break it awkwardly. Maybe I am going about trying to solve this problem incorrectly and I need to be using a different set of functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Truncate a string in PHP to the word closest to a certain number of characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-chara)

Comment: Thanks Brett.  I am hoping there is a different solution without doing a for loop to count characters.  That seems overly simplistic.

Comment: I tested that accepted answer and it will return higher than desired length.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to find the position of the first <kbd>space</kbd> after the first 155 characters. This can be done with `strpos($string, ' ', 155)`. Then use `substr($string, 0, $endat155)` to retrieve the portion of the string from the beginning to that position.

```
$endat155 = strpos($string, ' ', 155);
$firstWords = substr($string, 0, $endat155);
echo $firstWords;
```