# how to limit number of words in a description in php?

Tags: php, substr

I want to display a small intro of with a limited number of words without cutting the last word if it is too long... 
I know there is a php function substr() but it does not display the intro like "this is my starting text..." 
It makes it say "this is my starting t..." in PHP.
Thank you for any answer.

```
                    <a href="#">'.substr($rows['title'],0,50).'</a>
```

Comment: Find a space and `substr` to it.

Comment: Split into words and only take the first <n>.

Comment: how? @Marvin sorry! I didn't understand..

Comment: See Thanatos11th's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Truncate a string in PHP to the word closest to a certain number of characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-chara)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why not this:

```
implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $rows['title']), 0, 50));
```

1. explode all the words;
2. get first 50;
3. recreate the sentence containing only first 50 words;

Comment: There are better ways and faster ways to do this, this would take longer than cutting the text down.- See my answer.

Comment: I though he asked for a limit of words?